# I have different versions of node js (and lot of other things) in shell and node-ssh

Tags: node.js, ssh, virtual-machine, nvm

I am trying to do some automation scripts via [node-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh) but it behaves in a very strange way:

When I am using classical ssh (via terminal or vs code) node version is **10.16.3** and NVM command is available:

```sh
node --version 
v10.16.3
```

But when I am using library **[node-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh)** and command **execCommand** the node version seems **8.10.0** and NVM command is not aviable:

```js
import node_ssh from 'node-ssh';

const command = 'node --version';
const client = new node_ssh();
await client.connect(sshCredentials);
console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', command, '\x1b[0m');
client.execCommand(command , { cwd: remoteDir });
console.log(result.stdout);
```

```sh
node --version 
v8.10.0
```

---

Also, environment variables are different. I don't know what is here happening. I am using same server with same computer that connects on this server via ssh same user with same key file but it behaves differently.

The server is located on **DigitalOcean**.
It is **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**.
I am using root user with ssh key file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the problem:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/node-v-and-nodejs-v-different-output

It can be solved by installing node.js from official Ubuntu packages not via NVM.
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall